# Python array looking for contiguous maximum subarray index

Tags: python, arrays

I was preparing for interview questions first time before a python question and came across a convention in Arrays and don't find it in the python docs so seeing why it works. In the loop the statement :

**Update**
The array uses the inner loop to print the section largest. The question is the indexing as the range seems to be out of bounds by looking in i+j? What would xrange on this loop not be used as this has better structure?

```py
max = 0
for i in range(n - k + 1):
    max = arr[i]
    for j in range(1, k):
        if arr[i + j] > max:
            max = arr[i + j]
    print(str(max) + " ", end = "")
```

I do not understand what the arr[i+j]? I am thinking its just keeping a sum but when its back in the first loop its set back to arr[i] so I'm missing how this keeps accurate the largest sum as it moves through the array not seeing any descriptions for the inner bracket usage?
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-index3307/1

Answer (score 0):

I think it finds the largest sum, and then just prints it.
Then it "removes" the left index and does it again.
But basically it doesnt keeps the sum, it just prints it.

For the subarray [4, 3, 1, 4, 2]

the output (prints) would be:
7 6 6 6

Comment: I added statement to the question so check the change in the updated post.